# Printer Spooler fails to start

Tags: windows-7, printer, print-spooler

My print spooler has suddenly stopped working on Win 7.

There are no printers visible in `Devices and Printers` though the total count is still there. When I go to `Add a printer` i receive the error:

```
Windows can't open Add Printer. The local print spooler service is not running. 
Please restart the spooler or restart the machine
```

And then when I look at the running services `Spooler` says:

```
Failed to Read Description. Error Code: 193
```

I don't know where to start!

---

Update:

When starting manually, I get this error:

```
Windows could not start the Spooler service on Local Computer.

Error 1058: The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
```

Comment: Is that error what you receive when you try to start it manually?

Comment: @Kyle, added the error I get when manually starting to the question. Cheers

Comment: Make sure the service is set to login as local system, interact with the desktop, and that it is set to automatic.

Comment: Yes @Kyle, it has all those settings, in fact all the `start`, `stop`... buttons are greyed out now

Comment: Check to make sure that RPC Endpoint mapper is started and the DCOM Server Process Launcher is started.

Comment: Again, both started, the rest of the PC seems to be running OK.

Comment: Well everything is configured right maybe something is wrong with windows. Try running sfc/scannow in an elevated cmd window.